# Problems with using clj-oauth

Tags: oauth, clojure

I'm developing Twitter sign in for my platform. I want to use for this purpose clj-oauth library (https://github.com/mattrepl/clj-oauth). I added `[clj-oauth "1.5.2"]` to my `project.clj` and created seperate file `oauth.clj` for testing purposes with only this code:

```
(ns greenius.service.oauth
  (:require 
    ['oauth.client :as 'oauth]))
```

When I try compile `oauth.clj` I get error:

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Named  clojure.core/name (core.clj:1518)
```

I have an impression that I follow the guide in every bit. What could be the cause of that error?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ' because you are using the require from inside the ns macro, so the names have to be symbols.
Example from the [ns](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns) documentation:

```
    (ns foo.bar
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [ancestors printf])
  (:require (clojure.contrib sql combinatorics))
  (:use (my.lib this that))
  (:import (java.util Date Timer Random)
           (java.sql Connection Statement)))
```

Comment: I tried to do this. If I compile this:  
`(ns greenius.service.oauth
  (:require 
    [oauth.client :as oauth]))`  
I get `FileNotFoundException Could not locate oauth/client__init.class or oauth/client.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)`

Comment: Did you run lein deps after adding clj-oauth to the project file?

Comment: Yes. Strange thing, but after I rerun emacs, I get different error. Now it's: `CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts, compiling:(clj_http/conn_mgr.clj:1:1) `. I tried to google it and I think the reason are conflict between libraries. I'll post here if I find solution.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem.
First I followed th esuggestion given by @Razvanescu and changed `['oauth.client :as 'oauth]` into `[oauth.client :as oauth]`.
After that I was getting new error:
`FileNotFoundException Could not locate oauth/client__init.class or oauth/client.clj on classpath: clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)`.
When I reran my IDE it changed into `CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts, compiling:(clj_http/conn_mgr.clj:1:1)`
Googling that error led me to this: https://github.com/cemerick/friend/issues/128.
I was using friend 0.2.0 and `clj-oauth` uses `clj-http` so it applied to my problem. After I upgraded to `[com.cemerick/friend "0.2.2-SNAPSHOT"]` and reran my IDE the problem was gone and it works now.

Sad thing is that I realized just now that twitter grants info only about username, which in my case is practically useless for sign up...